# Show full Linux command line (gcc output)? (c programming on Virtual Machine)

Tags: c, virtual-machine, virtual

I am using a Linux VM in Oracle VirtualBox on Windows 10. I have developed a c program in nano and when executing gcc, following is shown:

[Screenshot VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opZGl.png)

Obviously some part of the error message is missing at the top. Is there a way to show this? Also can sb help me to interpret the message?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of the gcc command to `more` (or alternatively to `less`). Also, since gcc error messages are printed to the standard error and not to the standard output, you have to redirect the standard error to the standard output, with `2>&1`.
So, supposing that your gcc command invocation is `gcc myfile.c -o myprog`, you can do like that:

```
gcc myfile.c -o myprog 2>&1 | more
```

That will show you gcc output messages from the top; in order to scroll down, press ENTER; in order to return to the command line, press `q` (or alternatively scroll all the way down to the end of the output messages).

If you want to be able to scroll up and down, use `less`:

```
gcc myfile.c -o myprog 2>&1 | less
```

To scroll down, press the down arrow key; to scroll up, press the up arrow key; to return to the command line, press `q`.